# How to permit Active Directory - Integrated authentication and simultaneously prohibit Active Directory - Password authentication

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-authentication

I would like to provide to admin users an MS Access database which includes some ODBC linked tables to an Azure SQL Database.

Is it possible to allow *Active Directory - Integrated* authentication while prohibiting *Active Directory - Password* authentication? I.e., to force users to be on domain-joined machines.

If in addition to the MS Access database I also provide an ODBC data source which specifies *Active Directory - Integrated* authentication, a user could potentially create an ODBC data source that specifies *Active Directory - Password* authentication and re-link the tables on a local copy of the database. This would allow the user to access the Azure SQL Database on any machine irrespective of whether or not it's a domain-joined (company) computer.

Comment: I am not an AAD expert, but I am not aware how to do it using current SQL drivers. If you use AAD integrated you can always use U/P for this account

Comment: Indeed @MirekSSQLPM, I also suspect that it's not possible. However, one can restrict IP addresses in the Azure SQL Server firewall to domain-joined machines.